# Error: 'Invalid Return Type' When Retrieving Results from PostgreSQL View in C# Using ADO.NET or Dapper

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dapper

I'm trying to retrieve the query results from a view I created named vwindicador_separacao_pedido_inicio_separacao_fisica_resumo. The SQL query calculates certain indicators for a given id_grupocliente based on the EXTRACT function and some conditional logic. The result set consists of nr_ano, nr_mes, and pc_aferido.

Here is my C# code for executing the query and mapping the results:

```
string query =
    @"SELECT * FROM vwindicador_separacao_pedido_inicio_separacao_fisica_resumo WHERE id_grupocliente = @idGrupoCliente";

return (await conn.QueryAsync<IndicadorPortal>(query, new { idGrupoCliente })).ToList();
```

The **IndicadorPortal** class has three properties: **nr_ano**, **nr_mes**, and **pc_aferido**:

```
public class IndicadorPortal
{
    public int nr_ano { get; set; }
    public int nr_mes { get; set; }
    public decimal pc_aferido { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I run the code, I encounter the error:

```
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42601: invalid return type
DETAIL: Query-specified return tuple has 17 columns but crosstab returns 19.
```

It appears to be an error related to the number of columns returned, but my query does not use the crosstab function.

Here is the SQL code used to create the view:

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vwindicador_separacao_pedido_inicio_separacao_fisica_resumo;
CREATE VIEW vwindicador_separacao_pedido_inicio_separacao_fisica_resumo AS
SELECT
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_inclusao)                     nr_ano,
    EXTRACT(Month from dt_inclusao)                    nr_mes,
    sum(case
            when coalesce(iso.data_pedido_separado, now() ) > dt_prazofinalproducao then 0.00
            else 1.00 end::float) / count(*)  pc_aferido,
    a.id_grupocliente
FROM public.vwacompanhamento a
         INNER JOIN vwindicadorsemocorrencias iso ON a.id_sem = iso.id_sem
group by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_inclusao),
         EXTRACT(Month from dt_inclusao)
       , a.id_grupocliente
```

I have also tried using dynamic types and IDictionary<string, object> as return values, but the same error persists.

To troubleshoot, I tested the code using ADO.NET as well, but encountered the same error. I am seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres need to know the return type and structure during planning, therefore you can't just return a variable number of columns. I think, the probem is in this code:

```
sum(case
            when coalesce(iso.data_pedido_separado, now() ) > dt_prazofinalproducao then 0.00
            else 1.00 end::float) / count(*)  pc_aferido,
    a.id_grupocliente
```

If I am not mistaken, you are returning different number of columns in the `when` and `else` sections.